# Targetting Printer GPO to a Subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, print-server, group-policy

I'm aware that you can target specific printers via the individual `Item-level targeting` to a subnet.

I have about 20 printers that I would rather put the full group policy into maybe a WMI filter for a subnet 192.168.0.x. That way when a jr tech adds this and forgets to add the item-level targeting this will take care of it's self.

How would you target the full group policy object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [WMI filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779036(v=ws.10).aspx), but it's really ugly and unintuitive. There's no way to do this with Item-Level Targeting, as it only applies to Group Policy Preferences, which are a subset of configurable GPOs.

I always refer to [this blog post](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.com/2008/03/wmi-filter-for-subnet-filtered-group.html) when I need to do this instead of using Item-Level Targeting for some reason.

The WMI query that you'll be filtering on (from the blog linked to above) is:

> Select * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable
>   WHERE ((Mask='255.255.255.255' AND NextHop='127.0.0.1')
>   AND (Destination Like '10.0.0.%' OR Destination Like '10.0.1.%' OR Destination Like '10.0.2.%'))

In the example that you've provided, you probably want to use something like:

> Select * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable
>   WHERE ((Mask='255.255.255.255' AND NextHop='127.0.0.1')
>   AND (Destination Like '192.168.0.%'))

Comment: I couldn't get this to work till I followed the comments and said to add OR NextHop='0.0.0.0'. After that and a reboot I was able to get this to apply. Thanks again

Comment: Good to know! I think each case is OS specific. Glad it pointed you in the right direction, please feel free to edit the answer with the more correct info!